# Showing that $ e^{2x^2} + 2e^{x^2} + 2 = (e^{x^2} + 1)^2 + 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I cannot figure out how the left side is converted to the right side...can someone please explain? I have tried some factoring methods but it doesn't give me the right side.

$$ e^{2x^2} + 2e^{x^2} + 2 = (e^{x^2} + 1)^2 + 1$$

I tried Wolfram but all it says is True, doesn't show me how left side becomes right side.

Comment: Hint: do you see how the squared quantity multiplies out? If so, can you use that to factor the left hand side and get the result?

Comment: The equality is incorrect as stated. The lefthand side is "$+1$" larger than the righthand side.

Comment: I put in a correction as an edit on both the title and result, but it has yet to be approved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let $ a=e^{x^2} $,
Then the statement becomes $ a^2+2a+2=(a+1)^2+1 $,
subtracting 1 from both sides gives $a^2+2a+1=(a+1)^2$, which is an obvious statement, thus it must be true

Comment: it looks like completing the square from what I can tell. Using variable "a" makes it much clearer to see how they factored using complete the square method. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's much clearer to see how the right side becomes the left. To do this, you just multiply out $(e^{x^2} + 1)(e^{x^2}+1)$.